# maui: cant reference custom handler

Tags: c#, android, maui

I have set up a custom handler; for it to work I put it under my android main activity:

```
    public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    
          
                
                DependencyService.Get<IScannedData>()?.Invoke(scannedBarcode);
            }
        }
    }
    
//custom handler
    public class CustomCollectionViewHandler : CollectionViewHandler
    {
        private IItemsLayout ItemsLayout { get; set; }
    
        protected override IItemsLayout GetItemsLayout()
        {
            //return base.GetItemsLayout(); //Throws exception
    
            return ItemsLayout;
        }
    
        protected override void ConnectHandler(RecyclerView platformView)
        {
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
    
            ItemsLayout = VirtualView.ItemsLayout;
        }
    }
```

The reason why I put it here is because I cant seem to acecess the android specific parts like "RecyclerView" inside the maui project, it needs to be inside the android class.

Now I am trying to access my handler and registre it inside the mauiprogram.cs:

```
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(collection =>
{
    #if __ANDROID__
    collection.AddHandler<CollectionView, CustomCollectionViewHandler>();
    #endif
});
```

But it tells me it cant find CustomCollectionViewHandler anywhere.

I might have put it wrong,
can someone show me how it is done?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I have also set up this empty class with the same name inside shared code:

```
public partial class CustomCollectionViewHandler : CollectionViewHandler
{

}
```

Now I can access it in mauiprogram.cs but it doesnt trigger my android platform code...

Comment: Again, this is covered in the docs.  Platform specific handlers should be partial classes

Comment: Thank you, I put it into a public partial class right into the android platforms into the namespace: Platforms. This is still not found in MauiProgram.cs....

Comment: Do you also have a partial class in the shared portion of the code?

Comment: No, do I just need this class with the same naming inside the shared code? Just empty? As the custom props are only for android..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the empty class inside shared code and put the custom handler in the **\Platforms\Android**, such as:

```
namespace YourProjectName.Platforms.Android
{
    public class CustomCollectionViewHandler : CollectionViewHandler
    {
        private IItemsLayout ItemsLayout { get; set; }
    
        protected override IItemsLayout GetItemsLayout()
        {
            //return base.GetItemsLayout(); //Throws exception
    
            return ItemsLayout;
        }
    
        protected override void ConnectHandler(RecyclerView platformView)
        {
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
    
            ItemsLayout = VirtualView.ItemsLayout;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use the custom handler in the MauiProgram.cs:

```
builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(collection =>
{
    #if __ANDROID__
    collection.AddHandler(typeof(CollectionView), typeof(Platforms.Android.CustomCollectionViewHandler));
    #endif
});
```